# filtering pandas .isnull().any() output

Tags: python, pandas

(This question can probably be generalized to filtering any Boolean Pandas series, but nothing that I can find on that subject addresses my issue.)

Given this dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': (1, None, 3), 'b': (4, 5, 6), 'c': (7, 8, None), 'd': (10, 11, 12)})
df
     a  b    c   d
0  1.0  4  7.0  10
1  NaN  5  8.0  11
2  3.0  6  NaN  12
```

I need to get a list of **column names** that have NaN values in them (my real dataset has 80+ columns and for cleaning purposes I only want to focus on anything with NaN for the time being).  This will give me a full Boolean list:

```py
df.isnull().any()
a     True
b    False
c     True
d    False
dtype: bool
```

Ideally I only want:

```py
a     True
c     True
```

I cannot figure out how to do that.  A mask is close, but is applied to the row:

```py
mask = df.isnull().values
df[mask]
     a  b    c   d
1  NaN  5  8.0  11
2  3.0  6  NaN  12
```

Is there a way to apply them to the column axis instead, or is there a better way to do what I'm looking for?

Comment: Like the dupe says, `df.isna().any().loc[lambda x: x]` is the shortest way for your specific output

Comment: Try formulating the problem from the POV of what you _want_ to do ("I want to find columns that have...") as opposed to what you're trying to do that isn't working. Just a tip. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

You can perform indexing on the columns with your mask:

```
>>> df.columns[df.isnull().any()]
Index(['a', 'c'], dtype='object')
```

Or if you want to show the data for the given columns:

```
>>> df[df.columns[df.isnull().any()]]
     a    c
0  1.0  7.0
1  NaN  8.0
2  3.0  NaN
```

Comment: I didn't realize you could index .columns like that, but I knew I had to be missing something straightforward.  Good to know for the future.